# Android Authorisation in site via OkHtttp

Tags: android, apache, authorization, okhttp

I want to make authorisation in this site: http://psu.kz/student_cabinet/index.php?lang=rus.
 But when i try to run this code in activity:

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()

                        .add("user", mEmail)
                        .add("password", mPassword)
                        .add("delivery_key", "")
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(BASE_URL+route)
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();

                System.out.println(request);
                System.out.println(formBody);



                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

I have error in site. I just did not log in. I also tried online services but can not do that. What is my mistake? Can someone help?

Comment: What error are you receiving? Also what are the values of BASE_URL and route?

Comment: I can't get information from server. BASE_URL and route is  "http://psu.kz/student_cabinet/index.php?lang=rus" link

Comment: You need to be more specific. Are you getting an exception? Or is there a problem with the page you are getting? If there is an exception post the stacktrace. If there is no exception, print out the values of `response.code()` and `response.request().url()` and post them here.

Comment: Yes, there is problem with page, that i get. After request i did not authorise. And get main page again.